# Appending Rows to a DataTables Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to add `<tr/>` tags dynamically to a DataTable, but I didn't find actual good documentation on how the "adding TR process" is supposed to work.  I have this as my DataTables setup:

```
$("#Grid").DataTable({
   stateSave: true,
   fixedHeader: true,
   rowReorder: true,
   .
   .
   columnDefs: [
      { orderable: false, className: "seq-cell", targets: 0 },
      { orderable: false, targets: "_all" }
   ]
})
.on("row-reordered", function (e, diff, edit) {
   for (var i = 0; i < diff.length; i++)
   {
       ..
   }
});
```

I'm getting the definition of the item in the grid from an MVC action method as an HTML string, via a jQuery AJAX statement:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "AddItem",
    data: $("#newitemform").find(":input[name]").serialize(),
    success: function (d) {
       var $body = $("#Grid tbody");
       $body.append(d);
    }
});
```

The "d" parameter is the HTML for a row; I'm appending it to the body.  That adds correctly and but doesn't have the row reorder functionality enabled then.  What is the proper way to append to a DataTable, then re-enable whatever functionality?

Comment: Does the html for the row returned in the ajax vary? Or is it only the data inside that html that varies?

Comment: The HTML returned if always a TR element but only varies by data, not syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) API method to add a new row instead of appending to the table body.

If `d` contains string in the following format `<tr>...</tr>`, you could just use `$("#Grid").DataTable().row.add($(d).get(0))` to add a new row.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "AddItem",
    data: $("#newitemform").find(":input[name]").serialize(),
    success: function (d) {
       $("#Grid").DataTable().row.add($(d).get(0)).draw();
    }
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/52tmwkgr/2/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use Datatables API's to add rows to the table.  As indicated in the previous response you can use either [row.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) or [rows.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()).  The data needs to be in a data structure that matches your Datatables data structure config, ie, arrays or objects.

However it looks like you are receiving HTML structured data and appending directly to the table.  In this case Datatables is not aware of the added data.  You will need destroy ([destroy()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())) the Datatables table, append your data then re-init Datatables.  For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "AddItem",
    data: $("#newitemform").find(":input[name]").serialize(),
    success: function (d) {
       $("#Grid").DataTable().destroy();
       var $body = $("#Grid tbody");
       $body.append(d);

       $("#Grid").DataTable({
       stateSave: true,
       fixedHeader: true,
       rowReorder: true,
       .
       .
       columnDefs: [
          { orderable: false, className: "seq-cell", targets: 0 },
          { orderable: false, targets: "_all" }
       ]
    })

    }
});
```

Comment: There is no need to destroy the table, `row.add()` API method accepts `tr` node as an argument.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com yes I was able to achieve some success using that (this fork illustrates this is working via: https://jsfiddle.net/52tmwkgr/1/) however for some reason, in my exact situation it isn't still working which is really weird...  So this approach solves it for now.

Comment: @BrianMains, I forgot chaining `draw()` method, see [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/52tmwkgr/2/) where it works. I still believe there is no need to `destroy()` the table. Updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48492545/3549014) as well.

Comment: As @Gyrocode.com mentioned the `destroy()` method is not needed.  His example should work fine if your data structure matches the table structure.  I didn't realize, until now, that `row.add()` will append data in the format `<tr>...</tr>`.  Its good to know.