# How to refresh datatables on ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have seen many stackoverflow questions on this and none of the answers have worked for me.

I have a DataTable that is initialized on the template inside `<script>` `</script>` tags, but the JS function that is handling the ajax call is in a different file and is loaded on page load.

I have data coming into the ajax function as a JSON object, I am also replacing the rows of the table with the data I get from the JSON object, but the datatables part of it is not refreshed (For ex: If row is deleted and table is empty, empty message is not shown).

How do I do refresh/re-initialization of the datatables inside of the ajax success? I was pointed [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()), but the documentation is really vague there and was not much help.

Here's my code:

leads.html

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#leads_table').DataTable( {
        "bInfo": false,
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "There are no leads yet"
         }
      });
})
```

JS Function for Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr("action"),
    data: form.serialize(),
    type: form.attr("method"),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data)
    {
        $('#leads_table').DataTable({...}) // Tried this, but complains about a duplicate initialization

        //How do I refresh here?

        $("#leads_table tbody").html(data.html_leads_list);
    }
})
```

Comment: `$('#leads_table').ajax.reload()` ?

Comment: Consider using `ajax` option, as shown [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

Comment: This recent [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471361/appending-rows-to-a-datatables-grid) may have your answer.

Comment: @naivists The ajax.reload( ) did not work.

Comment: @raina77ow I have looked at that page and it mostly is talking about getting the data from another file

Comment: @KThorngren That thread is talking about adding a new row, I want to refresh the entire table

Comment: With a reference to your datatable, can't you just do `datatable.clear()` `datatable.rows.add(data.html_leads_list)` and `datatable.draw()`

Comment: @npearson Well, I certainly could do that, but I am unsure of its scalability, as the number of rows get bigger and bigger, won't it just use up more and more server power?

Comment: @Di437 I referenced that thread to show how using the Datatable API's you can add rows within `tr` tags.  @npearson has a good answer however you may need to use `datatable.rows.add($(data.html_leads_list))` to have jQuery create the nodes.  And `datatable` probably should be `$('#leads_table').DataTable()`.  You can also chain `draw()` for something like this `$('#leads_table').DataTable().rows.add($(data.html_leads_list)).draw();`.

Comment: First [`destroy`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) your initial datatable and then use `$('#leads_table').DataTable({...})` .